# Flutter: Como saber cuando ah pasado un 1 dia

Tags: date, flutter, timer, horas

Quiero crear un método que me permita saber cuándo ha pasado un día o 24 horas, porque tengo acceso a una API y quiero limitar el número de solicitudes a 20 por día, pero no sé cómo decirle a mi aplicación que ya ha pasado un día, para volver a habilitar las llamadas a la API.

Esto es lo más parecido que encontré en [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPhhEgpyVY8), que tal vez podría ser una solución pero no sé si sería la mejor manera de hacerlo.

Lo que hace es un contador, tipo temporizador que comienza en 10 a 0

```
int _counter = 10;
  Timer? _timer;

  void startTimer() {
    _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (_) {
      setState(() {
        if (_counter > 0) {
          _counter--;
        } else {
          _timer!.cancel();
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: buen día, yo creo lo estas haciendo mal, lo que tendrías que hacer es guardar en una base de datos local un contador por fecha, leerlo y actualizando en cada petición para al llegar a los 20 en para el día, cancelar la petición y al día siguiente validar, como ya será nueva fecha te deberá regresar 0

Answer (score 0):

Puede usar DateTime() en el paquete intl a determinar si es un dia nuevo o el mismo dia. https://pub.dev/packages/intl

```
var llamados = 0;
var hoy = '0000-00-00';

api() {

  if (hoy != DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(DateTime.now())){
    // Es dia nuevo. Reinicia vars llamados y hoy.
    solicitudeNuevo();
    llamados = 1;
    hoy = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(DateTime.now());
  }
  else {
    if (llamados < 20) {
      solicitudeNuevo();
      llamados++;
    }
    else {
      // Ya hay más que 20 solicidudes en este dia. Hacer nada.
    }
  }
}
```